# Makefiles, ifdef and computed variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make something that I think it's not possibile in make.
I have a common target which can have several prerequisite, like postbuild_% in this example

```
TARGET_NAMES = release.target.1.1 debug.target.1.1 release.target.2.4 debug.target.2.4
BUILD_TARGET := $(addprefix build_,$(TARGET_NAMES))    
.PHONY: $(BUILD_TARGET)
$(BUILD_TARGET): build_%: prebuild_% % postbuild_%
```

I use the definition of a variable (exported by another makefile which calls the one with the rules) for each target to determine a certain behaviour of the compilation. Since each target name is different (except for the release/debug thing), I use a different variable for each one. For example

```
.PHONY: %.target.1.1
%.target.1.1:
ifndef NO_target.1.1
    [something specific for %.target.1.1]
else
    @echo nothing to do
endif
```

now my problem is that even in postbuild_% I have to replicate this thing, but the recipe is always the same for every target, so I'm trying to find a way to use computed variables to recreate the "NO_$*" variable in order not to replicate the whole recipe, like this

```
POSTBUILD_TARGET := $(addprefix postbuild_,$(TARGET_NAMES))
.PHONY: $(POSTBUILD_TARGET)
$(POSTBUILD_TARGET): postbuild_%:
ifndef $(addprefix NO_,$(subst $(whitespace),.,$(wordlist 2,4,$(subst ., ,$*))))
    [...]
else
    @echo Skipping $@
endif
```

Something in this is clearly not working: what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make first parses all makefiles into an internal data structure, then runs the rules.  `ifeq` etc. are evaluated at the first step.  Automatic variables are not set until the second step.

You cannot use make preprocessor statements like `ifeq`, which are parsed *as the makefile is read in*, to query automatic variables like `$*`, which are not set *until the recipe is run*.

You'll have to use shell conditionals if you need to test some value per rule, like this:

```
$(POSTBUILD_TARGET): postbuild_%:
        if [ -z '$(NO_$(subst $(whitespace),.,$(wordlist 2,4,$(subst ., ,$*))))' ]; then \
            [...]; \
        else \
            echo Skipping $@; \
        fi
```

Comment: So that was my mistake :/
Thanks for the tip, I now have to find a way to translate that shell conditional into something portable since these makefiles are used in both windows and unix sistems :D

Comment: You can use the make `$(if ...)` function inside a recipe if you want to be more portable.  You just can't use `ifeq` etc. statements.

Comment: OMG thank you! I completely forgot about it :)
I managed to do solve my problem this way
`$(if $(findstring undefined,$(origin NO_$(subst $(whitespace),.,$(wordlist 2,4,$(subst ., ,$*))))), [...] , [...])`

thanks!